# <T> not finding type of object created through Activator

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have create an object using this syntax:

```
var newMessage = Activator.CreateInstance(client.Key);
```

It appears to create an object of the correct type and allows the object properties to be set.  However when I pass the object to a method with signature:

```
public void Publish<T>(T messageBody)
```

The Type defined by T is object.

How do I get around this?  I can't change the method signature - its from a library - and I need to be able to create objects at runtime without knowing their type beforehand.

**UPDATED**

The function I am trying to perform relates to sending(Publishing) messages.  Ordinarily I would register a message Handler like:

```
RegisterHandler<MyMessage> (m => do something with message );
```

and could then call

```
Publish<MyMessage> (message)
```

which would eventually end up at the handler.  This is cool and works fine.

What I am trying to do is insert an intermediary to act as an exchange and publish the message to multiple handlers.  I know there are other things I could use to do this for me such as RabbitMQ, but I was hoping to be able to achieve it with just a small modification to the current code.

So I have a method that registers subscriptions:

```
 public virtual void registerSubscription<T1,T2>()
    {
        if (handlerMap.ContainsKey(typeof(T2)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Message handler has already been registered for type: " +typeof(T2).Name);
        }
        if (!handlerMap.ContainsValue(typeof(T1)))
        {                              
            mqHost.RegisterHandler<T1> (m => distributeMessage(m) );
        }
        handlerMap[typeof(T2)] = typeof(T1);
    }
```

I call the method with two classes, a base class and a class that inherits the base class:

```
public class MyMessage
{
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public class MyMessage2:MyMessage{}
```

This bit works well and I get a map of handlers built up.  The problem comes when I do the next bit, the distributeMessage method.

```
var match = handlerMap.Where(i => i.Value == message.Body.GetType());
foreach (var client in match)
{
    var newMessage = Activator.CreateInstance(client.Key);
    newMessage.PopulateWith(message.Body);                
    messageProducer.Publish(createMessage(newMessage));                
}
```

The messageProducer.publish has the signature:

```
public void Publish<T>(T messageBody)
```

I can't (easily) modify this - it is part of a library.  There is another method I could call:

```
public void Publish<T>(IMessage<T> message)
```

But I can't see that this would be any easier as I would have to create a Message which still requires .

Comment: Remember that everything to do with *generics* is a **compile-time** feature. It doesn't matter that the runtime-type of `newMessage` is what you'd expect, the compiler can't tell what `T` is supposed to be.

Comment: Do you know anything about a type you create ? If you don't so there is no way that compiler will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use some reflection to try to create a generic method of Publish given the type information you knew when calling the Activator.  If I have misunderstood what you are trying to do, please ask and I can modify this code.

```
object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

var publishMethod = typeof(MessageProducer).GetMethod("Publish");
var publishMethodWithCorrectType = publishMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { myType });

publishMethodWithCorrectType.Invoke(messageProducer, new object[]{newObject});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Just posted an answer which does exactly this.  Not sure I understand the voodoo that's going on, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Try do this:

```
var newMessage = (MyType)Activator.CreateInstance(client.Key);
```

p.s. MyType is an base type or interface...

Comment: If the OP knows the type why did he use `Activator.CreateInstance`? He could just use `new`.

Comment: An small addition, you can you an interface instead it =)

Comment: I guess Publish requires exact type to be bound to T. If it didn't he could just use `T = object` which he said he can't. I hope he clarifies.

Comment: agree with first comment - this is not feasible

Comment: If he doesn't know obout base type, he should to invoke Publish via reflection, i'm agree =)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to invoke the `Publish<T>` method via reflection as well to continue along this route.

Another suggestion would be to make the `class` object's class generic based on the `client.Key` type, then implement a Publish method within that class - the implementation will know what `T` is.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/420969/1804544) to another question

and implemented this:

```
 typeof(MessageExchange)
   .GetMethod("createMessage",BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
   .MakeGenericMethod(newMessage.GetType())
   .Invoke(null, new object[] { newMessage });
```

I'm now getting the correct type being passed through.

Comment: I guess I wasn't fast enough, glad to see you solved your problem!